# Why are my hr tags faint (barely visible) sometimes?

Tags: html

Sometimes when I use an <hr> tag, it is displayed as barely visible in my page.  It is drawn, but one has to squint to see it.  Other <hr> tags on the same page are displayed visibly (the way I would like).  I can only claim to have seen this in Internet Explorer 8 and 9.  I have not tested my pages in any other browser.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Here's a screenshot.  (Bonus question: How many rep points do I need to be able to insert the image right in my question?)

[image: http://www.johnfitzpatrick.us:8080/uploader/upload/faintHR.png]

Comment: Do the pages all include the same style? and if not, are you changing the `<hr />` style in there?

Comment: Could you try and get a screenshot oh the phenomenon?

Comment: I'm not using any styles in the page.

Comment: Um, how do I add a screenshot?  Do publish it on a website and add a link?

Comment: Edit your question and you should be able to insert it. If you don't have enough rep points just post a link to it.

Comment: Guess I don't have enough points.  I have posted a link.  A little worried about what I may have exposed my itty bitty barely protected web server to.  But, well, life is for living, right?

Comment: Just edited the question and brought the image in-line. Also used imgur for hosting, rather than linking from Stack Overflow to your personal server. If you'd *rather* self-host, then you should be able to edit the src for the image

Answer (score 1):

USE THE ATTRIBUTE 
**`NOSHADE`**


This is how i do it:

```
hr noshade style="border: none; 
           color: #ffffff; 
           background-color: #ffffff;"
```